# compile error = multipartentitybuilder() is not public cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android, httpclient

can you help me find out what does the error below means? I don't know why I cannot access it outside the package, I mean what ACCESS SPECIFIER should I use?
 I tried using static and all specifiers but still I could not get rid of this error. I have been using it when the user takes a pic using the camera to upload the picture to the server.

Comment: Please share your `MultipartEntityBuilder` code. You probably made it a private class or you didn't specify an access specifier at all

Comment: _i know this question is asked before_ but i searched every where_ i did not found the correct ans_. Please just explain my question..that enough..

Comment: are u asking me MultipartEntityBuilder.class which built by andriod

Comment: Didn't know that. Thought it was a class made by you

Comment: sorry class is not made by me.. it provided by `import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `MultipartEntityBuilder` doesn't have a public constructor. Look at the documentation: 
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html

You should create your object by static method `create`:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
```

Comment: still getting same error..no changes..i would to like share code and image of error.. but stackoverflow.com is not letting me put whole code and image...

Comment: Sorry, seems like i didn't looked ur code...i seems to understand now..